# Installing Oracle Weblogic 12c ZIP file with command that activates installer

Tags: oracle, maven, weblogic12c

How to install Oracle WebLogic 12c ZIP file. I know there is a command that I can write and will activate an installer, but I don't remember it completely.

```
java -cpXXXX -jar ...
```

I will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command to install in the directory where the installation file is:

$ java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_quick.jar

or you can specify where the ORACLE_HOME will be be running:

$ java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_quick.jar ORACLE_HOME=

Hope it helps